# Insecure HTTP methods on RESTful webservices

Tags: rest

So, generally HTTP methods like PUT and DELETE are considered to be insecure.

However, it is recommended to use PUT and DELETE methods for RESTful API's.

Why is that these methods PUT and DELETE are not considered as insecure for RESTful API's

Comment: Are you exposing your RESTful API to be world-accessible or is it an internal API?

Comment: It is an internal RESTful API which is available to users after Authentication.

Comment: What do you mean with *insecure*? Where did you read that?

Comment: Generally HTTP methods like PUT and DELETE are considered insecure to implement since it gives the power to the user to DELETE or PUT any content in the web server, as opposed to just POST request with application specific funtionality

Comment: @Yogi -- your RESTful logic doesn't (have to) give the power to DELETE / PUT any content. You can restrict it in your own code.

Comment: The purpose of RESTful isn't remote file-handling (at all). It's presenting application interactions as if it were remote file-handling (over HTTP).

Comment: For example a RESTful HTTP PUT can send a JSON body containing the information for a WordPress article. Your RESTful service can take the JSON body an insert it as a database record into the WordPress database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR

They are considered insecure because a web-server's default behavior would directly impact files on the servers filesystem -- allowing executable code attacks.

A RESTful service doesn't (have to) create files based on the original request.

#### Internal / firewalled / proxied

An **internal** API -- is protected by the fact that it's in a private LAN. It is only accessible to other internal (trusted) tools.

Similarly a firewalled internal or external API only accepts requests from certain IPs (trusted servers).

A proxy server can handle encryption and user authentication as well as authorization and then forward the request to the RESTful service.

#### But still what are the security risks?

If PUT would create executable files on the server that would be very insecure** -- because of the risk of code injection / executable injection...

...but when receiving PUT or DELETE operations we're not talking about file-management per se. We're talking about a specific handler code which analyses the request and does whatever you told it to do with the data (eg.: puts it into a database).

**Especially since after you execute HTTP PUT on a resource (in a RESTful context) one would expect to have access to execute HTTP GET on that same resource (meaning the resource would be directly accessible).

Comment: I have always understood that there always has to be some code to handle the HTTP GET/POST/PUT/DELETE requests in order to perform an action. For eg: If I wanted to create a file I would trigger an HTTP PUT and the server will direct it to the code that matches that route and the handler code will be responsible for authorization and then execution of the request. I am not able to picture it outside of REST api. Could you give any example? Links perhaps?

Comment: Look into WebDAV, it's basically a file management protocol on top of HTTP.
Kinda like having an FTP server to work with files but it communicates through a webserver.
It's old, and it's been implemented in popular servers (or available via modules).